# Arduino "piston" device

Tags: project

Is there any compact piston-like devices on the market that can apply pressure safely various parts of the head? I can further expound if needed.

The ideal size would be something within the 1-2 inch length range

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "piston-like devices" that can "apply pressure safely various parts of the head"? Do you have an image or some sort of link to what you are talking about?

Comment: Do you need a particular pressure/force to be applied? I ask because it would be possible to use servo or other motor driven mechanisms, but force control would be more complicated with these. I thought of small Lego Technics pistons but some air source and valves would be needed.

Comment: Is this really an Arduino question yet? I think this should be migrated to EE (and modified to change title from "Arduino" to something less MCU-specific).

Comment: @CharlieHanson, I think the question is off-topic here and in [electronics.stackexchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) as well.  Possibly on topic in [robotics.stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest#), probably on topic in [engineering.stackexchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is nothing to do with an Arduino, just a general Electrical/Mechanical engineering question that you want to control from and Arduino. 
I think you wan a device that when signalled by your Arduino can extend itself by up to 2 inches.

If that is right then I think what you are looking for is a Linear Actuator.  There are plenty out there and some do handle the small stroke you want, but most of them appear to be 9 to 12V.  This means you would require a Darlington transistor or relay to control them from an Arduino.

If you require an extremely precise stoke length then I would recommend a stepper motor with a screw axel.  This would allow you much finer control over how far you pushed, but it would impose limits on what you could do and how it could be mounted.

- Can you provide more details on what you want to move?
- List item
- Is it heavy? Do you need lots of Torque?
- Are you pushing straight or do you need to push in an arc (i.e. a door)?
- What voltage supplies do you have available?
- How fast do you want it to move?
- Do you want it to move exactly the same distance every time?

The more info you can provide the better, but in answer to your original question Yes, it sounds like there might be so you plan is still on the rails.